# error in user control C# wizard creation

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

> Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Wizard
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            this.CurrentPage = page11;
            this.btnCancel.Enabled = false;
            this.btnFinish.Enabled = false;

            base.OnLoad(e);
        }

        private IPagePanel _currentPage;

        public IPagePanel CurrentPage
        {
            get
            {
                return _currentPage;
            }
            set
            {
                _currentPage = value;
            }
        }

        private void page11_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.CurrentPage == page11)
            {
                this.CurrentPage = (IPagePanel)page21;
                page21.Visible = false;
                page21.Visible = true;
                btnCancel.Enabled = true;
            }
            //else
            //{
            //    this.CurrentPage = _thirdPageWizardPanel;
            //    _secondPageWizardPanel.Visible = false;
            //    _thirdPageWizardPanel.Visible = true;
            //    _cmdNext.Enabled = false;
            //    _cmdFinish.Enabled = true;
            //}
        }
    }
}
```

The code shown above is of wizard which I wanted to create. Page1 and Page2 are user control pages which I use.

> IPagePanel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Wizard
{
    public interface IPagePanel
    {
    }
}
```

The user control Page1 and Page2 are in 2 separate namespaces.

```
namespace Page1
{
    partial class Page1
    {
        /// <summary> 
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary> 
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Component Designer generated code

        /// <summary> 
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.lblDescription = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // lblDescription
            // 
            this.lblDescription.AutoSize = true;
            this.lblDescription.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.lblDescription.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(228, 114);
            this.lblDescription.Name = "lblDescription";
            this.lblDescription.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(65, 20);
            this.lblDescription.TabIndex = 0;
            this.lblDescription.Text = "Page 1";
            // 
            // Page1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.Controls.Add(this.lblDescription);
            this.Name = "Page1";
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(547, 278);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblDescription;
    }
}
```

Error Message:

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'Page1.Page1' to
>   'Wizard.IPagePanel'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a
>   cast?)     21  32  Wizard

Comment: have you implemented IPagePanel on Page21

Comment: I added Page1 and Page2 user control in the same namespace where the Form1.cs is present. That means for all, one IPagePanel present in one namespace. But still I am getting this error.

Comment: If I typecast like this -'**this.CurrentPage = (IPagePanel)page11;**', then it builds but throws run time error 'Invalid Cast Exception was Unhandled - Unable to cast object of type 'Wizard2.Page1' to type 'Wizard2.IPagePanel'.'

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to do '**public partial class Page1 : UserControl, IPagePanel**', Thanks allot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `IPagePanel` on `Page1` and `Page2`

Page1.cs

```
public partial class Page1 : IPagePanel
{
    //Your implementation here
    ...
}
```

Page2.cs

```
public partial class Page2 : IPagePanel
{
    //Your implementation here
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is not working if Page1 and Page2 are in two different namespace.

Comment: It actually doesn't matter at all what namespace the pages are in so long as either the interface is qualified with its namespace or the interface's namespace is imported with a using statement. Also, the assemblies that define the pages must reference the assembly the interface is declared in

Comment: One more thing, if you've changed the namespace just by editing the code behind of the control, make sure it's changed in the .designer.cs file as well. If the namespaces don't match you're actually defining two different classes instead of one

Comment: I am getting error '**Error 5 Cannot implicitly convert type 'Page1.Page1' to 'Wizard.IPagePanel'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)** in Wizard

Comment: Where '**IPagePanel**' should be implemented? Inside Page1,Page2 and Wizard? For now I implemented in all three.

Comment: Unless something needs to call the methods guaranteed by IPagePanel on an instance of Wizard, you don't need to implement it there. Only on Page1 and Page2. Please verify that all parts of the partial classes Page1 and Page2 live in the same namespace as one another.